# Laravel 5.3 how to add psr-4

Tags: php, laravel-5, psr-4

Error Class 'Mylib\Mytest' not found

My routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   $rs = new Mylib\Mytest;
   //@FIXME:Del or comment this debug script in routes/web.php
    dd($rs);
    //return view('welcome');
});
```

composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
         "classmap": [
             "database"
         ],
         "psr-4": {
             "App\\": "app/",
              "Mylib\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

src/Mytest.php

```
namespace src;

class Mytest
{   
     function theTest() {
          return true; 
    }
}
```

already run composer dump-autoload -o 
also run composer update

Comment: You should use `namespace Mylib` instead of `namespace src` as declared in composer.json

Comment: That the way. tq [Skysplit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3551175/skysplit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Skysplit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3551175/skysplit), i should use namespace Mylib instead of namespace src as declared in composer.json